# Как сделать unique ID

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте мне очень нужна ваша помочь. Мне надо в yii2 сделать уникальную ID у меня есть example в php

```
$query->orderBy('v_r.vid', 'DESC');
$query->range(0, 1);
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
$new_unique = 'A1A1234A';
if(isset($results[0]->vid)) {

    $old_id = $results[0]->vid;

    $num_length = strlen((string)$old_id);
    switch($num_length) {
        case 1 : $need_number = 4; break;
        case 2 : $need_number = 3; break;
        case 3 : $need_number = 2; break;
        case 4 : $need_number = 1; break;
        default : $need_number = 0; break;
    }

    $get_a = rand ( 65 , 90 );
    $get_b = rand ( 65 , 90 );
    $get_c = rand ( 65 , 90 );

    $a = chr($get_a);
    $b = chr($get_b);
    $c = chr($get_c);

    $other_numbers = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,$need_number);

    $new_unique = $a.$old_id.$b.$other_numbers.$c;

}
```

как можно эту код использовать в yii спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать [функцию PHP md5()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.md5.php) вместе с timestamp полученную функцией [time()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php)

```
$new_unique = md5(time());
```

Тоже достаточно уникально

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен вопрос , но если нужно просто сгенерить уникальный id то :

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uniqid.php